# What (might) happen if I use fclose() when fopen() failed

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

Here is my relatively simple scenario, and I'm wondering if I can save myself a conditional and tidy the code up a bit.  Its production code that someone else wrote and I'm just tidying up.  It had no fclose at all, so all I have added is the conditional fclose() lines:

```
  FILE *fp;
  struct stat sb;
  /* snipped code */
  if (((fp = fopen (config_file, "r+")) == NULL) || (fstat (fileno (fp), &sb))) {
      syslog (LOG_ERR, "Fault. Unable to read config file");
      if (fp != NULL) {
          fclose (fp);
      }
      return -1;
  }
  /* code carries on after this */
```

The question is, do I really need to have the `if(fp != null)` in my code?  What are the implications of just doing an `fclose(fp)` without checking?  I had a read of the C89 standard but it wasn't clear to me from that what the results would be.

Cheers in advance

Steve

Comment: No, you don't, because `fp` is *guaranteed* to be null at that point.  Did you forget your earlier check? `if (((fp = fopen (config_file, "r+")) == NULL)`.  Your if statement is useless and will never be entered

Comment: You may have intended to put `||` instead of `&&` in the first `if` statement's condition.

Comment: Sorry, yes that should have been || not &&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fclose` on a null pointer has undefined behaviour. This means it could segfault or cause you problems. I would stick with your checks as they are good practise and make the code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I'll leave the conditional where it is.  Cheers

Comment: @Steve: The second check (`if (fp != NULL)`) along with the call to `fclose()` it protects is **not** necessary! As already mentioned by *Ed. S*'s comment on the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In BSD, `fclose( NULL )` will segfault.  I believe that the classic description of what *may* happen is that nasal demons may fly out of your nose, but am uncertain if the behavior is undefined or unspecified.  I've never considered it a terribly important distinction: just don't do it.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of anything flying out of any orifice is probably enough for me to keep the conditional in place :)